# Why is FileReader appending line break to files?

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, filereader

I'm trying to use FileReader to load dropped files, but there is a mysterious '\n' character being appended to the file if it does not terminate with one.

Drop a text file that does not terminate with a line break and see that the last character of the file will be a '\n' (code 10).

```js
let fileReader = new FileReader();

fileReader.onload = function(event) {
  let lastChar = this.result.charCodeAt(this.result.length - 1);
  
  document.querySelector("#last_char").innerText = lastChar;
  document.querySelector("#length").innerText = this.result.length;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < this.result.length; ++i) {
     console.log(this.result.charCodeAt(i));
  }
}

function drop(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();

  var files = event.dataTransfer.files; //It returns a FileList object

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var file = files[i];
    fileReader.readAsText(file);
  }
}
```

```css
* {

  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#drop_area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  border: 3px dashed #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_area" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="event.preventDefault()">drop a text file here</div>
<div>Last char:</div>
<div id="last_char"></div>

<div>Length:</div>
<div id="length"></div>
```

Comment: I played with your Fiddle and my own text file. Your code works fine. Are you absolutely sure that the file doesn't have whitespace at the end?

Comment: Me, too. I created a file containing `abc`, and it said 99.

Comment: Could it be that you're viewing the file on Windows with Notepad which doesn't render \n as a line break so it appears like it does not have a line break?

Comment: Yeah, thats kinda what happened. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is a Unix thing, unrelated with javascript at all. It seem that it will always terminate with a line break, whether you insert it or not, whether your editor shows it or not. So what was happening is that I was thinking my file didn't have a line break, because my editor was not showing it, when in fact it did.

Whoops!